# display div inside table cell with resizing

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside of a table cell with css value of display:none.  When I $.show() it, the cell is slightly expanding to the right.  This works fine when I use the visible property instead of display:none, but I do not want to reserve the height if it isn't needed.  I've tried various display properties as well as rearranging the css width, margins, and padding, as well as removing the background images.

```
   <div id='1'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='container'>
                <div class='error'>I am some long ass error that breaks my layout and I can't figure out what to do.</div>
                <div>header</div>
                <div>
                    <input type='button' value='add to cart'/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </td>
        <td>
<div class='container'>
                <div class='error'>I am some long ass error that breaks my layout and I can't figure out what to do.</div>
                <div>header</div>
                <div>
                    <input type='button' value='add to cart'/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class='container'>
                <div class='error'>I am some long ass error that breaks my layout and I can't figure out what to do.</div>
                <div>header</div>
                <div>
                    <input type='button' value='add to cart'/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

    #1{width:400px;}
table {width:100%;}
tr {border: solid grey;}
.container{
    border-right: 1px dotted #A5A5A5;
    margin: 25px 0;
}
div {

    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.error {
    display:none;
    padding-left:20px;
    width:80px;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle showing the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/kv6DS/1/)

Comment: well, I will post on meta j08691 but less people will view it there and therefore there is less pressure to actually change the requirement of having formatted code when using jsfiddle.  A really burdensome design...

Comment: my bad, I didn't update the fiddle, try the link now.  Problem is that the columns change size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this to the CSS.  This may not work when the table width is undefined or very small.

```
table {width:100%; table-layout: fixed;}
```

Or

```
td {width: 33.33%;}
```

Comment: yeah, I went with percentages calculated in jquery based on the number of table th, going to try this table-layout fixed though

Answer (score 0):

While adding a static width to .container will solve your problem like so:

```
.container{
   border-right: 1px dotted #A5A5A5;
   float: left;
   margin: 25px 0;
   width: 250px; 
}
```

I might recommend doing away with the table and some of those div wrappers all together and using something a little more semantic.
It seems like it is more of a list of items than tabular data, so you might consider putting it in an Unordered List instead.

I have put up a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZYztj/

Answer (score 0):

Adding two attributes `cellspacing="0"`, `cellpading="0"` to the `<table>`,  and
CSS rule:

```
tr, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Will fix your issue completely and cross browser.

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mArvb/)

Also, never use id name starting with the number, like `#1`, 'cause it can fail in some browsers.

Comment: This didn't fix the issue when I tested on Chrome.

Comment: yeah, that id was just for the fiddle.  It could have easily have been 'asdf'